# Most efficient way to write (init, last) in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am new to Haskell, so as an exercise, I wanted to implement a function that was similar to `uncons` that returns both the `init` and `last` elements in a list. The easy way to write this function is

```
initLast :: [a] -> ([a], a)
initLast xs = (init xs, last xs)
```

I'm new to writing haskell programs, but this seems inefficient to me, as it will have to iterate through the list twice. I came up with another function that I thought might be better for not iterating through the list multiple times:

```
initLast' :: [a] -> ([a], a)
initLast' [x] = ([], x)
initLast' (x:xs) = let (xs', y) = initLast' xs
                   in (x:xs', y)
```

But it turns out that when I run these in ghci, I see that the second version is twice as slow, and uses approximately 3 times the memory!

```
ghci> :set +s
ghci> snd (initLast [1..1000000])
1000000
(0.28 secs, 122242144 bytes)
ghci> snd (initLast' [1..1000000])
1000000
(0.71 secs, 434147544 bytes)
```

### The Questions:

1. Why is the second version less efficient?
2. Is there a more efficient way to implement `initLast`?

Comment: Challenge: implement your algorithm as `initLast = fromJust . foldr go Nothing where go ....`

Comment: if _"similar to `uncons`"_ then surely it should be `unsnoc :: [a] -> Maybe ([a], a)`?

Comment: `lastInit [x] = (x,[]);
lastInit (x:xs) = fmap (x:) (lastInit xs)`

Answer (score 9):

As usual: compile if you're going to do performance tests. The compiled version uses about the same time for both, but 67MB for `initLast` and only 6MB for `initLast'`.

Comment: "but 67MB for initLast and only 6MB for initLast'" really? They both run in the same time and space on my machine... which makes sense to me, because I would think they should be equivalent due to laziness.

Comment: @user2407038 Really. They are not equivalent because the former makes two passes over the data (hence must hold the entire input list in memory during the first pass), while the latter makes only one. Perhaps you are not compiling with optimizations or something...?

Comment: Nevermind.. I was testing like in the OP, only taking the second element. I see it was simply optimizing away the code which computed `init`, and I guess the tuple in `initLast'` was optimized away too... when consuming the entire result the discrepancy appears.

Comment: somewhat off topic.. Since init and last are independent and xs is immutable.. can not compiler optimize it to only one pass on list ?

Comment: @AshishNegi Depends what you mean by "can". If you mean "is the compiler allowed to according to the spec", yes, definitely. If you mean "is GHC smart enough to notice this", no, empirically not. If you mean "could one in principle design a compiler smart enough to notice this", well, I guess, but [hoping for a sufficiently smart compiler is probably a mistake](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?SufficientlySmartCompiler).

Comment: @DanielWagner I'm pretty sure this sort of loop fusion is supported by some compilers and/or libraries. There has certainly been work on similar things in Haskell, but it's a bit over my head.